# Система быстрых ответов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Разрабатываю модуль технической поддержки пользователей сайта.

Суть его такова: пользователь заходит в центр поддержки и оставляет заявку со своей проблемой. Админ заходит и отвечает, вроде все стандартно и ничего особенного. Но проблема в следующем, количество поступающих заявок очень большое, а проблемы зачастую схожи. И дабы не набирать ответ каждый раз на одинаковые заявки хочется сделать "быстрые ответы".
Тоже вроде ничего сложного. Готовые ответы делятся по категориям, в зависимости от типа заявки. Количество быстрых ответов может быть тоже большое (например 30-50шт. для одной категории).

Проблема в следующем: как сделать так, что бы можно было быстро находить нужный ответ, а не перечитывать каждый (если каждый читать, то быстрее будет уже вручную набрать :)). Может кто занимался подобным... В общем прошу не помощи в создании, а просто у кого какие есть идеи на этот счет.

Мои идеи:

- использовать тэги;
- испльзовать поиск по базе like'ами.

Но, честно говоря, не знаю насколько это будет эффективно, а главное удобно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть вариант попробовать сделать самообучающуюся систему. Заготовить несколько десятков хороших ответов и вначале ручками добавлять в качестве ответов. Потом взять какую то готовую  [нейронную сеть](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) и натравить на это дело.
Но совсем уж доверять ей я не стал и поэтому интерфейс для ответов вижу так:
вверху сам вопрос, внизу несколько вариантов, которые подобрала система. В таком случае часто ответы на типичные вопросы будут занимать пару секунд.

По поводу "готовых ответов". Это должны быть короткие и лаконичные ответы, типа "проверьте версию браузера", "попингуйте наш сервер", "у нас была техническая проблема, сейчас исправлено". Выбирать можно галочками несколько возможных ответов, а пользователю уйдет письмо вида

```
добрый день, пользователь
мы Вам советуем сделать так
1) проверить версию браузера
 для этого сделаейте то, то  и .... (тут ссылки на FAQ, на утилиты для проверки)
2) попингуйте наш сервер
 тут расписано как это делать.
...
```

Таким образом удастся уменьшить кол-во потенциальных ответов для выбора, нейронная система сможет более точно подбирать, в списке ответов на вопрос будут показываться только названия ответов (иногда и жаргонными словами, понятными только админу).

Comment: Отлично. Нечто подобное щас и сам обдумывал. Только подумал ввести рейтинг наиболее часто используемых ответов в разделе и выводить, допустим, топ-5 ответов. А рядом окошко с поиском ответов по ключевым словам и выделением ключевых слов другим цветом, как предложил @ImirofF.

Comment: рекомендую, разместить рядышком ещё ссылку/вкладку, где пытаться найти предыдущие вопросы этого этого человека.

Потому, что если человек в 10 раз задает один и тот же вопрос, а мы отвечаем одним и тем же ответом, то может у нас плохой ответ? или человеку нужно просто лично написать.

Answer (score 1):

Натолкну на идею реализации...

И так:

- 1 - Создаем в БД таблицу типа
     **ready_answers** и загоняем пару полей типа question и answer. Понятно
     что в question записываем возможные
     вопросы, в answer ответы.
- 2 - Далее через форму отправляем с
     помощью jquery запрос к определенному
     скрипту. Катаем php скрипт(алгоритм)
     который вычесляет процент схожести
     хранящегося в БД вопроса. Вычесляем схожесть выводим ответ с
     наиболее высоким процентом схожести.
     Так же создать минимальный процент
     схожести, допустим 25% при котором
     выводить инфу типа - нет быстрого
     ответа на ваш вопрос, обратитесь к
     онлайн консультанту!

Написать словами проще чем реализовать кодом, но суть я думаю понятна.

Пример работы того о чем я написал можно увидеть [тут](http://www.webmoney.ru/rus/about/demo/index.shtml) Введите Ant'у вопрос "Как дела?".

Comment: На самом деле, если применить алгоритм Левенштейна, то все просто. Хотя не ручаюсь за скорость работы на больших объемах...

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Правдо с муравьем что-то не прокатывает. Пустое окошко выкидывает ))